# Using find command on other directories?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, administration

The command `find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -delete` deletes everything within the current directory and recursively deletes the files from there.

What needs to be updated within this command so that it just removes all files within a specified directory e.g. `/users/user/desktop`?

Comment: hint: `-maxdepth`

Comment: hint: ``man find``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` command takes its first argument(s) as director(ies)
in which to perform its action.

A single dot `.` represents the current directory. 
(Two dots `..` represents the parent directory.)  That means your command deletes all files with a `.jpg` suffix in (and under) the current directory.

To delete all files with a `.jpg` suffix in another directory, for example,
`/Users/username/Desktop`, you'll simply use

```
find /Users/username/Desktop -type f -name '*.jpg' -delete
```

This will also affect all sub-directories.

Add option `-maxdepth` to limit sub-directory levels. The command

```
find /Users/username/Desktop -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -delete
```

deletes files with the `jpg` extension from the `Desktop` folder only; it doesn't access folders inside (below) the Desktop.

Comment: Note that you can list multiple directories; e.g., `find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type f ...`